# MySQL InnoDB whats the difference between Data_Length and Max_Data_Length

Tags: mysql, linux, relational-database, innodb

So here is the table status of my test table:

```
+------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| TEST | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 172713 |           1175 |   203096064 |       202309632 |            0 |   5242880 |         181935 | 2015-07-21 23:52:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
```

Table is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, att VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL);
```

I heard from some one that Max_data_length used to be a fixed value and it is usually 4gb. But in later version of mysql they change the definition of Max_data_length. So now Max_data_length will grow as you insert more data (just like data_length).

I am wondering whats the new definition of Max_data_length and how is it different from Data_length?

Thanks!

Erben

Comment: Funny enough Data_length is larger then Max_data_length. Can you post your create table?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I think max_data_length used to be a fixed value like 4gb. But in a later version of mysql they change its definition. It start from 0 and will increase as you insert more data into the table, just like "Data_length". So I am wondering whats the new definition of "Max_data_length" and how is it different from "data_length"...

Comment: It is storage engine dependent: Hence the CREATE TABLE question :). MyISAM is supposed to be limited to the 4GB limit. You might be right that that is an old limit since file systems maximum file sizes are now up to 2^64, so a bit bigger then the 4GB mark. Since MySQL is not always file system aware and MyISAM is a single table=single file solution, the 4GB limit might also just be an internal limit they keep in place. I myself am running InnoDB (almost exclusively besides some in memory tables) with tables larger then 100GB without any issues.

Comment: I have updated the questions with create-table command. I am using innodb. Curious whats the definition of Max_data_length in InnoDB...

Comment: That is answerable: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html : Summary: The MAX_DATA_LENGTH for a single row with data is 4GB.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen - MyISAM is not limited to 4GB.  It used to have a default max, but even then it could be overridden.  InnoDB has a hard limit of 64TB.

Comment: I have only seen `Max_data_length` = 0 for InnoDB.  What version are you running?

Comment: On the other hand, `Data_free` has some interesting values -- depending on `innodb_file_per_table` and whether the table is `PARTITIONed`.

Comment: Nothing in any changelogs about `Max_data_length` (except for something about engine=Archive).